# httpd not starting because it cannot bind to port 80. Nothing running on port 80

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

After installing new cert and trying to restart the httpd service I keep getting this:

```
$ httpd -X
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I check syntax:

```
$ httpd -t
Syntax OK
```

service check gets me this:

```
$ systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-04-21 18:36:25 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 254501 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 254501 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

for journal xe I get this:

```
 sudo journalctl --no-pager -u httpd
-- Logs begin at Fri 2023-04-21 13:58:29 UTC, end at Fri 2023-04-21 19:12:22 UTC. --
Apr 21 13:58:47 domian.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 21 13:58:49 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 13:58:49 domian.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 21 13:58:49 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 13:58:49 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Apr 21 15:12:48 domian.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 21 15:12:48 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 15:12:48 domian.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 21 15:12:48 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 15:12:48 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Apr 21 18:09:59 domian.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 21 18:09:59 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 18:09:59 domian.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 21 18:09:59 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 18:09:59 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Apr 21 18:11:21 domian.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 21 18:11:21 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 18:11:21 domian.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 21 18:11:21 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 18:11:21 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Apr 21 18:15:43 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
Apr 21 18:36:25 domian.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 21 18:36:25 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 21 18:36:25 domian.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 21 18:36:25 domian.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 21 18:36:25 domian.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

there is nothing on port 80

```
xxxx@domain conf.d]$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep --color :80
[xxxx@domain conf.d]$
```

Not sure what else to do to get httpd started?

partial output of sudo netstat -an

````
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:199           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7373          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6062          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1935            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6162          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8126          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4352          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45288         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48962         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:49170         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45610         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47764         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47626         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          127.0.0.1:49010         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48872         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45778         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:47260         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:48332         127.0.0.1:6379          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45336         127.0.0.1:6379          TIME_WAIT  ```
````

Comment: The output you included is truncated. Can you edit your post with the output of `journalctl --no-pager -u httpd`?

Comment: yes let me do that now

Comment: ok edited the question and added the output of your command

Comment: WHat is the result of `sudo netstat -an`?

Comment: On your first command, the `$` prompt indicates you are trying to run `httpd -X` as a non-root user. Since it's configured to use port 80, that will certainly fail. When starting via `sudo systemctl start httpd.service` or otherwise using `sudo`, it should be able to get the ports but might run into a different issue. Apache has its own logs: see `/var/log/httpd/error.log` and other log files in the same directory.

Comment: @RomeoNinov it is a large output - Going to add it to the question

Comment: @telcoM I should have added that I have used sudo in the question - it is the same result ```sudo systemctl start httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Since Apache can produce a large volume of logs, it has its own log files... but `systemctl` does not know that. Please check Apache's own error log as I suggested above.

Comment: @telcoM logging in and checking it right now

Comment: I would try `sudo apachectl restart`. The `$` prompt with administrative command without sudo shell puzzle me.

Comment: @telcoM the only logs in that directory are access_log and ssl_request_log - no error logs. Going to track down if the httpd error log is stored somewhere else

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer yup already tried that ```sudo apachectl restart
\Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
``` - going to update the question to show that this has already been tried

Comment: If the Apache configuration is in the usual location, then `grep -r ErrorLog /etc/httpd` might be helpful in finding the error log.

Comment: Is it possible you have `docker` running on this machine, or some other container platform?

Comment: @aviro yes it has docker running on it

Comment: Maybe there's an `iptable` rule that forwards port 80 to one of the containers. Check the ports your `docker` containers are listening to: `docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}"`. Also check the iptable rules you have: `iptables-save`, see if there's anything with port 80.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems access to ports below 1024 is restricted. Did you try running on a port above that or start httpd as root?

Comment: yes tried sudo "sudo service httpd restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: regarding using a different port - this server has been running for the last 260 days with problems. I updated the cert and when trying to restart httpd - it just went to this state

Comment: Was the new cert created using the old private key, or a new one? If the latter, did you also update the private key file (usually in `/etc/pki/tls/private/`)? A key/certificate mismatch would cause Apache to fail at startup. Since CentOS has SELinux by default, you might need to verify the certificate and private key files have the correct SELinux labels (`ls -lZ` should say `system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0` for them).

Comment: the old key and I got the cert from the same issuing authority. - But let me go check that now

Comment: @telcoM ```unconfined_u:object_r:cert_t:s0 ```

Comment: Okay, `cert_t` is usually the important part, and `unconfined_u`/`system_u` might be just a difference between CentOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that someone else put an old key into the cert dir and that caused httpd to not have permission to bind to port:80. Thank you all for great suggestions and answers.